# C -- Modify const through aliased non-const pointer

Tags: c, constants, compiler-optimization

Is it allowed in standard C for a function to modify an `int` given as `const int *` using an aliased `int *`? To put it another way, is the following code guaranteed to always return 42 and 1 in standard C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const int *a, int *b)
{
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    *b = 1;
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 42;
    foo(&a, &a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example code, you have an integer. You take a const pointer to it, and a non-const pointer to it. Modifying the integer via the non-const pointer is legal and well-defined, of course.

Since both pointers are pointers to integers, and the const pointer need not point to a const object, then the compiler should expect that the value read from the const pointer *could* have changed, and is required to reload the value.

Note that this would not be the case if you had used the `restrict` keyword, because it specifies that a pointer argument does not alias any other pointer argument, so then the compiler could optimise the reload away.

Comment: Because some vote based on status of the other answers instead of their knowledge. The "logic" goes like this: since there was another downvoted answer saying yes, therefore my answer must be incorrect as well. Another explanations is that someone is simply plain wrong and just a very zealous voter.

Comment: The guy asking the question is down 3 points since asking it, so I guess they downvoted, if you lose 1 point per click.

Comment: @DarrylMiles what? what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Re the downvote policy, as I wondered too who downvotes new answers without any comment?  Maybe someone can point me to the SO folklore on this ?  It has to do the comment made here.

Comment: @DarrylMiles People downvote (and upvote) in bizarre fashion all the time. I don't think there's any enforceable policy, but if you want rumours maybe try searching meta.
I read an interesting thing recently. Paraphrased: "Look at all the questions you think are incredibly stupid. Now realise that questions like that indicate some significant portion of users who might be happy to upvote those questions". Same thing applies to downvotes.

Comment: @DarrylMiles re the OP (potentially) losing 3 rep, downvoting costs 1 rep, but downvotes remove 2 rep and there is 1 downvote on the question, so we really shouldn't assume anything from that, hence my confusion about your original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes. Your program is defined.

The fact that you point to an non-const int variable with a pointer to a const int, doesn't make that variable const and may be still modified trough a pointer to an int or by using the original variable label.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this (if you know you can get away with it).

One reason you may not be able to get away with it, is if the destination memory you are writing to is in a read-only protected areas (such as constant data) then you will get an access violation.  For example any const's at compile time that end up in read-only data sections of the executable.  Most platform support protecting it from being written to at runtime.

Basically don't do it.

There are other issues with your example that probably don't make it the best demonstration.  Such as needing a reload of *a in the 2nd printf the compiler may optimize it out!  (it knows 'a' did not change, it know's 'a' points to a const, therefore, it does not need to reload memory by preforming a memory load for the 2nd '*a' expression, it can reuse the value it probably has in a register from the 1st time it loaded '*a').  Now if you add in a memory barrier between, then your example has a chance of working better.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier
GCC ?   asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");  // might work before 2nd printf

But the principal for the actual question you asked, yes you can do it if you know what you are doing about other stuff like that.

Comment: Any compiler optimizing the reload out, for the second printf belongs in a trashcan. No barrier is required. *then your example has a chance of working better.* All I can say to this is: ???

Comment: Please cite spec that forbids such an optimization.

Comment: You are arguing that it can optimize it out, therefore you must cite the part that allows it. (Of course that is impossible.)

Comment: @DarrylMiles The `restrict` keyword exists to allow such an optimisation - it's not something that is allowed happen by default.

Comment: Maybe you are right, can't prove either way on a quick test with GCC (both with and without `__restrict__`), I've always worked on the basis that such optimization is possible, since '*b =1;' is an expression whose side-effects the compiler fully understands, therefore *a is already known by it the 2nd time around.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Got it working with GCC -O6 as `void foo(const int * const __restrict__ a, int * __restrict__ b)`  the 2nd 'const' did the trick.  Now -O0 and-O6 there is a change in output. I can confirm you are correct that `restrict` allow this optimization to happen.  Adding the memory barrier makes it always work too, forcing that 2nd reload. :)

Comment: @DarrylMiles According to the spec, the compiler isn't obliged to do the optimisation in the presence of `restrict`, merely allowed to (sort of like how `inline` doesn't actually force inlining), so I'm not surprised you had to wrestle with the compiler a bit to make it happen. See 6.7.3.1.6 *"A translator is free to ignore any or all aliasing implications of the uses of `restrict`"*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is guaranteed to always print 42 and 1.

`const int *a` means the value pointed to is a constant for pointer `a`.

Try dereferencing from `a` (`*a = 10;`) in the function and you will get an error.

The pointer `a` however is not constant. You can do `a = b` for example.

`b` can point to the same address as `a` and/or modify the value, as you did in your example.
Would you declare `b` pointer's value to be constant (`const int *b`), you would receive an error.

I try to memorize like this:

`const int *a` - a points to an object of type int, which it is not allowed to modify (any other pointer to that object can do what it wants, depends on its declaration/definition).

Comment: You are giving the right answer, but your explanation is using incorrect terms. ( I did not downvote )

Comment: Don't worry about downvote. That's SO. I am interested what terms you mean are not OK?

Comment: I see. No problem. The OP doesn't use `constants` at all, so I imagine there is no confusion.

Comment: @Elyasin While we're talking things to fix, *"const int *a - a points to a read-only object of type int"* isn't true. It doesn't have to point to a read only object, although it may do. It's just that the object must not be modified through the const-qualified pointer.

Comment: @IskarJarak That's what I am saying. For `a` it is read only, then in parens any other pointer can do what it likes. It is read-only for `a`, and depends for other pointers. Isn't that the same?

Comment: @Elyasin I know that's what you mean, but it's not the same as pointing to a const object. The object pointed to does not have to be const (nor read-only), it just can't be modified through a const pointer. The distinction seems subtle but it's actually pretty important for this question, where some other pointer can alias it and change the object pointed to.

Comment: @Elyasin `const` means you are able to modify `a`, but you should not attempt to modify `a` because you might not have the permission (it may be stored in a read-only section of memory; writing to that address can crash the program with a segfault.) Read-only means you are completely unable to modify it, even if you wanted to try.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I am not really sure. If you try `*a = 10;` you should get a compiler error (*error: assignment of read-only location `*a`*). `a` is not allowed to modify the value it points to. Is it relevant where the value is stored? I don't think so.

Comment: @Elyasin It is definitely relevant. If you make a const object and that object happens to get stored in RO data, and then you cast away the const and modify it, your program will compile (probably with a warning about casting away the const qualifier), but crash. If that object doesn't get put in RO data, your program will compile, and run, but exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's true. But I think that is being over-academic. In the example there is no cast. But good to let the OP know of course.

Comment: @Elyasin Academic or not, your edited version is much better.